# Docker In Docker - SSL problems

Tags: docker, ssl, jenkins, curl, docker-in-docker

I'm using Docker In Docker for Jenkins Slaves in our CI Pipeline.

I have run into an issue regarding SSL.  The issue is maven can't access artifacts located in our Nexus repo, it simply hangs.

I tried using curl for debugging.

Inside the DinD container, all is fine:

```
$ curl -I https://www.google.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

If however I run:

```
bash-4.3# curl -I --insecure  https://nexus.eng.myco.com/nexus
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to nexus.eng.myco.com:443`
```

it hangs for a long time and then I get this error:

```
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to nexus.eng.myco.com:443`
```

I can run the problematic `curl` statement one level up (the docker container that is running the problem docker container), all is good.

I should note that if I run the problematic DinD container on my laptop (not in DinD though), it has no issues.

update with debug info:

```
bash-4.3#  curl -v -I https://nexus.eng.myco.com/nexus/content/groups/this>
*   Trying 54.164.137.27...
* Connected to nexus.eng.my.com (44.164.137.27) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's too late to answer, but I will put it here in case of other strangers with similar problem.
I would suggest to check MTU in parent and child containers.

```
ip addr | grep mtu
```

In case you see that difference in MTU
e.g.

```
3: eth0@if14: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1402 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
```

it needs to be corrected to be the same.
e.g.

```
ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1500
```

Comment: Actually not, docker container mtu can me smaller neither hosts, they should not be strictly identical. It's a known problem when you use docker inside openstack network. Default openstack mtu is too small, so docker mtu should be changed to 1450 at least.